# Change button on "<a>" element in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add logout options in my bootstrap menu. After adding, an awful uneven button is created (as in the picture below).

[image]

How to add the logout form below so that you do not create such a button.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans 'Sign Out' %}</button>
</form>
```

My **template.html**

```
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-sm dropdown-menu-right">
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Menu użytkownika</h6>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i>Ustawienia konta
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <span class="float-right badge badge-primary">4</span>
            <i class="fas fa-car"></i>Ogłoszenia
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <span class="float-right badge badge-warning">2</span>
            <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>Zakończone
          </a>

          <!-- I try change this element on my hidden log out form-->
          <div class="dropdown-divider" role="presentation"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
            <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt">Log out</i>
          </a>

        </div>
```

Expectations (without gray background)

[image]

Comment: What would a good, even button look like to you?

Comment: I added expectations above.

Answer (score 1):

To make a button look like your last screenshot, you are going to want to tweak the `background` and `border` properties. More specifically, you are going to want to get rid of both of them, which you can do with this CSS:

**NB:** You are going to want to make this CSS more specific to that button, for example, with a class. If you put this in as-is, it will apply to all buttons.

```css
button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

That should leave you with the clickable area of the button, but it will make it clear, so all the user will see is the text and icon in the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .btn-primary-outline as a class on your button

Answer (score 0):

It solved my problem.

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'account_logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if redirect_field_value %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}"/>
    {% endif %}
    <button type="submit" class="dropdown-item">
      <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Wyloguj się
    </button>
  </form>
```